# uploading files using filetransfer plugin on cordova ios

Tags: ios, cordova

Im using jquery with cordova to build an app , on android everything works like a charm , but on ios the uploading is not working using filetransfer plugin .

this is the function i use to upload the picture that the user select already using the file plugin :

```
function uploadFile() {
    var fileURI = $("#selectedPicture").attr("src");
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, serviceURL+"uploadFile",function(r){
        alert(r.response);
    }, fail,
        options);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

on the console i don't get any error or message .
i added those to lines on my infoplist file :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
<dict> 
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

PS 1 : i use ios 9.2

PS 2 : i use cordova 6 .

PS 3 : the normal ajax works great only the upload thats not working .

PS 4 : i test the code using the latest ios simulator .

Comment: So even the failure callback isn't firing?

Comment: @Devgeeks i don't get any failure callback that's the problem neither on the xcode debug nor javascript console .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was from the image size i tried to upload .
i just selected an other image and i got what i was looking for .